# clang compiler does not support -fxray-instrument on aarch64-apple-darwin

Tags: c++, llvm, instrumentation

I'm trying to test llvm-xray but it seems it is not working as per their documentation. https://llvm.org/docs/XRay.html

```
$ clang++  test.cpp -arch arm64   -O2  -fxray-instrument -fxray-instruction-threshold=10
clang: error: the clang compiler does not support '-fxray-instrument on aarch64-apple-darwin19.4.0
```

Am i missing a flag, or xray isn't supported for arm64

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the page you linked, emphasis mine:

> As of July 25, 2018 , XRay is only available for the following architectures **running Linux**: x86_64, arm7 (no thumb), aarch64, powerpc64le, mips, mipsel, mips64, mips64el, NetBSD: x86_64, FreeBSD: x86_64 and OpenBSD: x86_64.

So it does support arm64, but not on Darwin, only on Linux.